# Cheap play tunnel construction

Tags: landscaping, hard-landscape, concrete

What is a good way to create a horizontal underground play tunnel?  I.E. through a mound, for children / dogs to play in or someday for storage.

This is a new construction on flat ground.  Large diameter concrete pipes seem very expensive (over £100).

Comment: We need more details: how tall does it have to be, how long, what is your budget.   I think if you want safe and dry and easy to install without power machinery it is going to cost more than the figure you mention

Comment: plastic PVC pipe and mounding works

Comment: @kevinsky Hi.  I wish we were as far as a budget - still at the stage of balancing the costs of this or that.  We are thinking of the tunnel being just about big enough for an adult to crawl through, I guess - maybe with a 'hobbit' door.  Also, a disappearing waterfall (ideally starting on the mound, for extra height) and a 'treehouse'.  This house came with a back garden of gravel, purple slate and slabs.  I guess the gravel could be a base for the mound.  The garden in our old house (rented) had centuries old trees in it, so a more woodland feel is the aim here.